# Classification of text articles found in different PDFs

Tags: classification, nlp, supervised-learning, text

I am trying to figure out the approach to connect articles present in different pages or PDFs. The historical data that I have are:

- Text Articles (broken down in headlines, body text, body headline and media caption and the PDFs names that they are found). I have gotten this in a XML format and I converted it in a Json file that looks like:

```
    {
         "Headline": "This is a Headline",
         "Byline": [
              "This is another BYLINE"
         ],
         "BodyHeadline": [
              "and the the body headline"
         ],
         "BodyText": [
              "This should be a large text paragraph",
              "another sentence in the body text",
              "the last sentence in body text"

         ],
         "MediaCaption": ["If there is media caption"],
         "PDF": [
              "X11#0001.pdf",
              "X11#0002.pdf",
              "X11#0003.pdf"
         ]
    }
```

As you see this article is included in three different PDFS. What I would like to do is to build  a model that classifies/predicts this article in different PDFs. i.e., to which PDFs is this article connected to.

The PDFs are mostly readable and I am using PyMuPDF (aka "fitz") for getting the JSON output. This provides information regarding blocks of texts in PDFs such as font, size, bbox location and text. A sample of one PDF would look like this (I just show 2 blocks but it could contain more):

```
{
     "PDF": "X11#0001.pdf",
     "Blocks": [
          {
               "block_bbox": [
                    -0.5304872064644457,
                    0.9683844633175651,
                    0.5304879430798047,
                    0.9793545233723604
               ],
               "block_idx": 0,
               "text": [
                    "a text sentence",
                    "other sentence"
               ],
               "font": [
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro"
               ],
               "size": [
                    7.0,
                    7.0
               ],
               "line_bbox": [
                    [
                         -0.5304872064644457,
                         0.9683844633175651,
                         -0.4695114902929961,
                         0.9793545233723604
                    ],
                    [
                         0.4695122269083551,
                         0.9683844633175651,
                         0.5304879430798047,
                         0.9793545233723604
                    ]
               ],
              {
               "block_bbox": [
                    0.0789473460541895,
                    0.7554111799458375,
                    0.41483171058858515,
                    0.9036320824132956
               ],
               "block_idx": 1,
         
               "text": [
                    "This is a sentence ",
                    "another sentence",
                    "sentence3",
                    "another sentence again",
                    "yes, another sentence",
                    "continue...",
                    "continue...",
                    "continue...",
                    "another text",
                    "almost there ",
                    "final sentence"
               ],
               "font": [
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro-Bold",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro-Bold",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro",
                    "TEOSOK+ScalaSansPro"
               ],
               "size": [
                    8.0,
                    8.0,
                    8.0,
                    8.0,
                    8.0,
                    8.0,
                    8.0,
                    8.0,
                    8.0,
                    8.0,
                    8.0
               ],
               "line_bbox": [
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.7554111799458375,
                         0.08266079406682393,
                         0.7680569142930777
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0790216167143238,
                         0.7689795537757371,
                         0.16631733627647055,
                         0.7816252881229773
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.7825479276056366,
                         0.3965036438661926,
                         0.7950850917740988
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.7961163014355362,
                         0.41483171058858515,
                         0.8086534656039984
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.8096846752654359,
                         0.38098440483292206,
                         0.822221839433898
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.8232530490953355,
                         0.3889415222598362,
                         0.8357902132637977
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.8368214229252351,
                         0.3813557156365535,
                         0.8493585870936973
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.8503897967551347,
                         0.41312355623389646,
                         0.8629269609235968
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.8639581705850342,
                         0.38012281984518836,
                         0.8764953347534964
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.8775265444149338,
                         0.37606483416408437,
                         0.890063708583396
                    ],
                    [
                         0.0789473460541895,
                         0.8910949182448334,
                         0.3819320604922132,
                         0.9036320824132956
                    ]
               ],}
```

Any ideas about how can I approach this problem and in which manner can I structure the data?

Comment: What is the total number of unique pdf’s you have?

Comment: @Uday I got a lot. The data is structured in magazines  (I got around 430) and each magazine has maybe around 100 PDFs and less articles (as 1 article can be contained in more than 1 PDF)